# Find the number of adjacent element trios with given sum

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find the number of adjacent element trios with a given sum.

**Example:**

Inputs arr = [1,2,3,12,1,4,9,6] sum = 6

Output = 2

([1,2,3,12,1,4,1,6])

**My Code:**

```
function getCount(arr, sum) {
  
  var count = 0;
  var indexes = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length-2; i++) { 
    for (var j = i + 1; j < arr.length-1; j++) {
      for (var k = j + 1; k < arr.length; k++){
        if ((arr[i] + arr[j] + arr[k] == sum) && indexes.includes(i) && indexes.includes(j)) {
          count++;
        }
      
      }

    }

  }

  return count;
}

getCount([1,2,3,12,3,4,9,6],19);
```

But this is not work for adjacent elements.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a single loop/pass here:

```js
function getCount(arr, sum) {
    if (arr.length < 3) return 0;

    var count = 0;
    var first = arr[0];
    var second = arr[1];
    var third;

    for (var i=2; i < arr.length; i++) {
        third = arr[i];
        var currSum = first + second + third;
        if (currSum == sum) ++count;
        first = second;
        second = third;
    }

    return count;
}

console.log(getCount([], 3));
console.log(getCount([1, 2], 3));
console.log(getCount([1, 2, 3], 3));
console.log(getCount([1, 2, 3], 6));
console.log(getCount([1,2,3,12,3,4,9,6], 19));
```

The strategy here is to just walk down the input array once, keeping track of the current, previous, and previous previous values at each step.  Then, we compute the sum of those three values, and compare against the input target sum.